# My thread/timer collecting data from serial is running only once

Tags: python

I tried rewriting the code listed here

https://github.com/Klebiano/Accelerometer-FFT---Real-time/blob/master/Acel_FFT_pyq_Versio3.py

I used QtDesigner to design UI and I'm having troubles that my code stops and doesn't read any serial data.
It looks like the timer/thread runs once and then stops so it's not reading serial buffer.
The code should read from arduinoData and if there's enough samples(limit variable) then it should provide those samples to numpy fft function and populate datax/y/z variables. And then graph them using pyqtgraph but it's not done yet.
I think that in the original code there were no classes or functions and the main loop was just firing the timer over and over again to read serial but how to implement this behavior in my code?

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QComboBox
from mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow, QtWidgets
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget, plot
import pyqtgraph as pg
import sys
import glob
import os
import threading
import serial
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import numpy as np
from collections import deque  # import a "circular" list
from threading import Thread, Lock
from itertools import islice
import pyqtgraph.exporters
import scipy.misc
import matplotlib
import time

arduinoData=[]
freq = 740  # 1/T
limit = 740  # 500
acelx = deque([], maxlen=limit)
acely = deque([], maxlen=limit)
acelz = deque([], maxlen=limit)
datax = []
datay = []
dataz = []

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #Load the UI Page
        uic.loadUi('mainwindow.ui', self)

        self.Button.clicked.connect(self.onSaveBtnClicked)
        self.listCOM.clicked.connect(self.onListBtnClicked)
        self.connectbtn.clicked.connect(self.onConnBtnClicked)
        self.disconnectbtn.clicked.connect(self.onDisconnBtnClicked)
        self.filenamein = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QLineEdit, 'filenamein')
        #self.plot()

        # frequencia = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(2.0*(1/freq)), int(limit/2))
        self.frequency = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0 / (2.0 * 1 / freq), freq // 2)



    def onSaveBtnClicked(self):
        print('Zapis do pliku wykonany: ' + self.filenamein.text())
    def onConnBtnClicked(self):
        print('Połącz z portem: ' + self.comboBox.currentText())
        usb = self.comboBox.currentText()
        arduinoData = serial.Serial(usb, 2000000)  # 115200
        print (arduinoData)
    def onListBtnClicked(self):
        print("Searching")
        self.comboBox.clear()
        # Reads the available serial ports
        if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
            ports = ['COM%s' % (i + 1) for i in range(16)]
        elif sys.platform.startswith('linux') or sys.platform.startswith('cygwin'):
            ports = glob.glob('/dev/tty[A-Za-z]*')
        elif sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
            ports = glob.glob('/dev/tty.*')
        else:
            raise EnvironmentError('Unsupported platform')
        result = []
        for port in ports:
            try:
                s = serial.Serial(port)
                s.close()
                result.append(port)
            except (OSError, serial.SerialException):
                pass
        print(result)
        for i in range(len(result)):
            self.comboBox.addItem(result[i])
    def onDisconnBtnClicked(self):
        print("Disconnect")
    def plot(self):
        print('plot')
        self.data_line = self.graphWidget.plot()
        self.graphWidget_2.plot()
        self.graphWidget_3.plot()

    arduinoData = serial.Serial('COM6', 2000000)  # 115200

    def data_input():
        print('datainput')
        # print(arduinoData)
        global datax  # , i
        global datay  # , i
        global dataz  # , i
        for line in arduinoData:
            try:

                print('collecting')
                acelx.append(float(line))
                print(len(acelx))

                if len(acelx) == limit:
                    datax = np.fft.fft(acelx)
                    datay = np.fft.fft(acelx)
                    dataz = np.fft.fft(acelx)
            except ValueError:
                print('notcollecting')
                pass

    t = Thread(target=data_input)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    print('daemon')

    def updategraph():
        # curve1.setData(deque(islice(acelx, 1500, 2000), maxlen=500))
        print('update')
        # curve1.setPos(i, 0)
        if len(acelx) == limit:
            print(datax)
            self.data_line.setData((2 / limit * np.abs(self.datax[1:np.int(limit / 2)])))
            curve2.setData((2 / limit * np.abs(datay[1:np.int(limit / 2)])))
            curve3.setData((2 / limit * np.abs(dataz[1:np.int(limit / 2)])))
    timer = pg.QtCore.QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(updategraph)
    timer.start(100)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()

    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

# start the data input thread. This will run in the background unaffected by the GUI.
```

https://pastebin.com/9XTP1EXe

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables - it is called "print debuging"` - and maybe you will see when and why it stops. (PL: najpierw użyj `print()` aby zobaczyć, które linie kodu się wykonują i co masz w zmiennych kiedy zaczyna się problem.)

Comment: if you want to run `data_input` all time then inside `data_input` you should put code in `while True: ...` . Or you should run it with `QTimer` instead of `Thread`. And by the way `PyQt` has class `QThread` and `PyQt` may preferred it.

Comment: Thanks @furas , 'while True:' in data_input worked just fine, my fft function is getting fed with data. But I have a problem with program flow now - I need to declare ser = serial.Serial('COM6', 2000000) at the beginning of the program so ser variable is globally accesible. But my idea was to select COM port in the UI and click Connect button(as in def onConnBtnClicked(self):). Any idea how I can declare ser variable to be global yet don't open any COM ports, just wait for user input from UI?
In the example from github it was done before starting main program with input fuction - in console.

Comment: it doesn't have to be global - you need it only inside `data_input` so you can create it at the beginning of `data_input`. and close at the end of `data_input`